# Quickly copy short string from binary file, as hex, to text file, in loop + partial MD5 calculation

Tags: arrays, string, powershell, binary, md5

I'm trying to create a PowerShell script that would, for each binary file in a folder : 1) read a short string at a fixed offset near the beginning (for instance 16 bytes at offset 1024) ; 2) copy that string as hex values to a text file (preferrably in the form “\xFC\x70\x28\x4C\x00”, or at least in a form that can be easily edited as such), with a line break. The goal is to create a list of search terms for WinHex, [to find matches between two groups of files from a data recovery made with R-Studio](https://superuser.com/questions/1440606/many-fragments-of-files-recovered-how-to-find-which-ones-belong-to-existing-fil).

I did the same request (with some added context) at [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/1547598/extract-x-bytes-at-y-offset-of-input-files-and-add-it-to-the-end-of-one-output-f), but couldn't get quite what I need. Based on someone's suggestion I tried this :

```
foreach ($file in gci *.mts, *.vob, *.mpg) {
$16Bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::Default.GetString([System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes("$file"), 1024, 16)
Add-Content -path "G:\search terms.txt" -value $16Bytes
}
```

It works but that was before I realized that a list of search terms in ASCII characters wouldn't be reliable (issues with null bytes), so I need to convert the output to hexadecimal values. Someone linked [this article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-powershell-and-regular-expressions-to-search-binary-data/), but I got errors when trying to add the `[System.BitConverter]::ToString` command to the script above, and couldn't get further. On [this page](https://eddiejackson.net/wp/?p=23393) I found a way to convert a byte array to a hexadecimal string formatted like I need : `[bitconverter]::ToString($16Bytes).Replace("-", "\x");` — but again I fail to combine this with the other commands.

The other issue is that the above script seems to be reading each file in its entirety before extracting the requested string, making it very inefficient, as there's about 1TB of files to process. I would need a way to parse only the requested portion of each file, which should be very quick. Based on [this thread](https://powershell.org/forums/topic/parsing-a-file-ith-binary-data/), `Get-Content` would have the same drawback, but no better approach was provided there, so again I got stuck. [Here](https://hostingultraso.com/help/windows/parse-manage-binary-files-windows-powershell) I found more specific information but it's way too vague to be of any practical use.

> For extremely large files, though, it may be unacceptably slow to load the entire file into memory when you work with it. If you begin to run against this limit, the solution is to use file management classes from the .NET Framework. These classes include BinaryReader, StreamReader, and others.

My current knowledge of PowerShell is very limited, my understanding of each part of each command is very fuzzy, which makes it very painstaking to assemble these snippets of code gathererd here and there in a way that makes sense, and most of the time when I attempt to run a command I get a big dump of red lines, error warnings that I don't understand, and since they're in french I can't even use them as search terms to find a possible solution since most resources about PowerShell are in english. This is all very frustrating, especially knowing that it drives me further and further away from the task I want to accomplish, which may not even deserve that kind of effort in the first place...

Then, if I manage to accomplish this first part, and if the search with WinHex works as intended, an extra step would be to perform automated checksum comparisons. WinHex can do a “logical search” within a whole volume, meaning that for each search hit, it can report the absolute offset (relative to the start of the partition) as well as the file offset (where the searched string was found within a file identified through that partition's filesystem, even if it is fragmented or NTFS-compressed). So, once I have the list of search hits, with the path / names of the files and the offsets where the string was found, what I would like is to : 1) compute the MD5 checksum of file “A” (the one from which the search term was copied) ; 2) compute the MD5 checksum of a block in file “B” (the one where a hit for the search term was found) which supposedly coincides with file “A” ; 3) print the result to a report file, and indicate if both values match or not. If the MD5 checksums match, it means that file “A” is totally and exactly included in file “B”, and can therefore be deleted ; if not, either it's a false positive (the search term wasn't specific enough, or the original file was fragmented so the recovered file may contain foreign data), in which case it has to be manually checked. [EDIT] To do that I would have to define, for each pair of files, in a loop, a block within file B starting at `{offset where the hit was found in file B} - {offset where the search string was copied from file A}`, and ending at `{starting offset} + {size of file A} - 1`. Then calculate the MD5 checksum of this block in file B, the MD5 of the whole file A, and report if both values match or not. For instance : if WinHex finds a hit for the search term obtained at offset 1024 from file 12345.mpg inside VTS_01_1.VOB at offset 1049600, and the size of 12345.mpg is 20971520, then I would need to calculate the MD5 of a block in VTS_01_1.VOB starting at `1049600 - 1024 = 1048576` and ending at `1048576 + 20971520 - 1 = 22020095` ; and compare the result with the MD5 of the whole 12345.mpg file. [/EDIT] I already know a command line tool called [dsfo](https://web.archive.org/web/20191211120635/http://members.ozemail.com.au/%7Enulifetv/freezip/freeware/) which can calculate the MD5 checksum of a block within a file, so I could use that as a workaround, but it would be more streamlined to do it all in PowerShell.

Thanks.

---

**EDIT :**

When I try to add the ToString command :

```
foreach ($file in gci *.wmv) {
$16Bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::Default.GetString([System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes("$file"), 1024, 16)
$var = [bitconverter]::ToString($16Bytes).Replace("-", "\x"); Add-Content -path "G:\search terms.txt" -value $16var
}
```

I get this error for each file :

```
Impossible de convertir l'argument « 0 » (valeur «                  ») de « ToString » en type « System.Byte[] » : « Impossible de convertir la valeur «                  » en type « System.Byte[] ». Erreur : « Impossible de convertir la valeur «                  » en type « System.Byte ». Erreur :
 « Le format de la chaîne d'entrée est incorrect. » » »
Au niveau de ligne : 3 Caractère : 32
+ $var = [bitconverter]::ToString <<<< ($16Bytes).Replace("-", "\x"); Add-Content -path "G:\search terms.txt" -value $16var
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodArgumentConversionInvalidCastArgument
```

---

**UPDATE 20200628 #1 :**

Based on the suggestions by Theo, after installing PowerShell 5.1, I tested this script on a folder containing 8 MKV video files :

```
foreach ($file in gci *.mkv) {
    $buffer = [Byte[]]::new(16)
    $stream = [System.IO.FileStream]::new($file.FullName, 'Open', 'Read')
    $stream.Position = 65536
    $readSize = $stream.Read($buffer, 0, 16)
    $stream.Dispose()
    if ($readSize) {
        # create a hex string and write to file
        $hex = for ($i = 0; $i -lt $readSize; $i++) { '\x{0:X2}' -f $buffer[$i] } -join ''
        Add-Content -Path "G:\search terms.txt" -Value $hex
        }
    }
    $buffer = $null
```

It works almost as intended, the values are correct (verified with WinHex), and it's very quick (took a split second to process all 8 files with a total of 2.64GB), but in the resulting text file there is only one byte per line, so it has 128 lines instead of 8. It looks like this :

```
\xE9
\xF6
\x4B
\x72
\x6C
\x6B
\x47
\xBC
\x48
\xD5
...
```

It should look like this :

```
\xE9\xF6\x4B\x72\x6C\x6B\x47\xBC\x48\xD5\x4A\x2B\x6E\x12\x8F\xDB
\x3C\x20\xD7\xFD\xB4\x63\x55\x57\xB3\x0D\x95\x99\x24\xF5\xCB\x85
\x72\x88\x2B\xBF\x0B\xC6\xE2\x5F\x1F\xB2\x72\x3C\xD3\xBB\x21\xA3
\xA4\x6F\x78\x6F\xA1\x2C\x1C\xD6\x17\x84\x3D\xDC\xB8\xBB\x20\x54
...
```

So how can I tweak this script to get this output ?

Also it would be nice to have a brief explanation for each command, particularly the `$hex = ...` line.

---

**UPDATE 20200628 #2 :**

I tried this :

```
$hex1 = [System.BitConverter]::ToString($buffer).Replace("-", "")
$hex2 = for ($i = 0; $i -lt $readSize; $i++) { '\x{0:X2}' -f $hex1[$i] } -join ''
Add-Content -Path "G:\search terms.txt" -Value $hex2
```

But the output is now half a byte per line, and each line stops at half the 16 bytes string :

```
\xE => beginning of string 1
\x9
\xF
\x6
\x4
\xB
\x7
\x2
\x6
\xC
\x6
\xB
\x4
\x7
\xB
\xC
\x3
\xC => stop halfway through string 1
\x2 => beginning of string 2
\x0
...
```

Then if I do this :

```
$hex = [System.BitConverter]::ToString($buffer).Replace("-", "\x")
Add-Content -Path "G:\search terms.txt" -Value $hex
```

It works with PowerShell 5.1, the output is almost what's expected, there's only one “\x” missing at the beginning, I could work with that, and add the missing character to each line with a text editor. But it would be better to get the intended output right away, at this point it shouldn't be difficult.

```
E9\xF6\x4B\x72\x6C\x6B\x47\xBC\x48\xD5\x4A\x2B\x6E\x12\x8F\xDB
3C\x20\xD7\xFD\xB4\x63\x55\x57\xB3\x0D\x95\x99\x24\xF5\xCB\x85
72\x88\x2B\xBF\x0B\xC6\xE2\x5F\x1F\xB2\x72\x3C\xD3\xBB\x21\xA3
A4\x6F\x78\x6F\xA1\x2C\x1C\xD6\x17\x84\x3D\xDC\xB8\xBB\x20\x54
E4\x76\x1A\x79\x7C\x77\xA0\x83\x80\xCD\x46\x80\x78\x25\x64\x07
35\xD3\xBD\xDD\xD9\xA2\x5D\xF2\x70\x1A\x07\x72\xEE\xB4\xE0\x24
5A\x25\xA5\x48\x6A\x61\x48\xF5\xA3\xFD\x14\xED\x09\x84\xF9\xB4
47\x02\xF5\x81\x81\x6B\x54\xB0\xB1\x6F\xCD\x90\x11\xAB\x09\xA2
```

Comment: `$var = [bitconverter]::ToString($16Bytes).Replace("-", "\x"); Add-Content -path "G:\search terms.txt" -value $var`. Is this what you want? I don't see an issue of the code that you've provided from superuser.

Comment: Based on your title, are you trying to copy strings in a all of a certain type of file into one text file and then do an MD5 calculation on the file? Is that correct?

Comment: To use a non-third party application md5sum checker (well wsl isn't third party) you can use `echo text (or output of any command) | bash -c "md5sum"` or full `bash -c "echo test|md5sum"` and with variable `bash -c "echo $var |md5sum"` and to perform operations on the variable `bash -c "$($var.tolower()) | md5sum"`

Comment: @NekoMusume 1) See the edit for the error message I get when adding the "[bitconverter]::ToString" line to the script (sorry it's in french as mentioned above). Based on the eddiejackson.net article I made this test : `[byte[]]$Bytes1 = Get-Content "E:\ST9500325AS.txt" -Encoding byte` // `[bitconverter]::ToString($Bytes1).Replace("-", "\x");` -- it works. I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: 2) There are 2 distinct parts to the intended task. First copy short strings from each file to create a list of search terms in order to run a simultaneous seach with WinHex. Then, once I (hopefully) have a list of search hits obtained from WinHex, I would need another script to calculate checksums and verify if each file from group A is exactly and entirely contained in its (larger) counterpart from group B. It's like a duplicate file search, but where the duplicate has to be searched at any position within other files, not at the beginning (I gave more details at SuperUser, it didn't help).

Comment: 3) See comment above – the goal is to calculate MD5 checksum of a block within a file. With dsfo, the command `dsfo video.mpg 1024576 2048 $` calculates MD5 for a block of the file video.mpg starting from offset 1024576 with a size of 2048 bytes. Same as defining a block with WinHex between 1024576 and 1026623 then using Tools > Compute Hash > MD5. I could do that with dsfo and the basic command line, but calculations in CMD are limited to 32 bits which may be a problem. I could use dsfo with PowerShell but don't know how to do the required calculations. I added an edit to explain this better.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR**

You can use a `[System.IO.FileStream]` object to read the bytes into a byte buffer and calculate the MD5 for those bytes inside the same loop.

Something like this:

```
$offset = 1024
$length = 16
$hasher = [System.Security.Cryptography.HashAlgorithm]::Create('MD5')

$result = Get-ChildItem -Filter '*.mts', '*.vob', '*.mpg' -File | ForEach-Object {
    # Old PowerShell versions need this:
    # $buffer = New-Object Byte[] $length
    $buffer = [Byte[]]::new($length)

    # Old PowerShell versions need this:
    # $stream = New-Object System.IO.FileStream -ArgumentList $_.FullName, 'Open', 'Read'
    $stream = [System.IO.FileStream]::new($_.FullName, 'Open', 'Read')

    $stream.Position = $offset
    $readSize = $stream.Read($buffer, 0, $length)
    $stream.Dispose()
    if ($readSize) {
        # create a hex string and write to file
        $hex = for ($i = 0; $i -lt $readSize; $i++) { '\x{0:X2}' -f $buffer[$i] }
        $hex = $hex -join ''
        Add-Content -Path "G:\search terms.txt" -Value $hex

        # calculate the MD5 for this block of bytes
        $md5 = $hasher.ComputeHash($buffer, 0, $readSize)
        # output an object with more useful stuff to export as CSV later
        [PsCustomObject]@{
            FileName   = $_.FullName
            SearchTerm = $hex
            SearchMD5 = [System.BitConverter]::ToString($md5) -replace '-'
            # or if you rather have the hash in Base64 format:
            # SearchMD5  = [Convert]::ToBase64String($md5)

            # you can also add the hash of the file itself here:
            # FileMD5 = (Get-FileHash -Path $_.FullName -Algorithm MD5).Hash
        }
    }
    $buffer = $null
}
$hasher.Dispose()

# output on screen
$result | Format-List

# output to CSV file
$result | Export-Csv -Path "G:\search terms.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

---

**Some explanation**

The code reads a portion of the file using `$readSize = $stream.Read($buffer, 0, $length)`.

`$readSize` then contains the number of bytes actually read into the `$buffer` array.
This *may not* be the same size as expected. For instance: here the buffer is 16 bytes long. The bytes left in the file as from `$offset` may not have this many bytes left, so $readSize could be less.

Next, we want the bytes in a certain format (`\xNN`) so it is possible to store it in a text file and use it in a regex search expression.
This is done with:

```
$hex = for ($i = 0; $i -lt $readSize; $i++) { '\x{0:X2}' -f $buffer[$i] }
```

This converts the raw bytes into their HEX representation, preceeded by `\x`
`$hex` is now a string array that needs to be joined together to form a single string, which is easy enough by doing

```
$hex = $hex -join ''
```

Then for the format of the output:
Since Hash values are quite long strings, displaying in the console as a Table (with Format-Table) will most likely not fit the width of the console, so there I chose the `Format-List`.

This way, all properties of the PsCustomObject we created are written out each on a separate line.
It's up to you how you want that displayed. Try `Format-Table -AutoSize` if you like that better, but remember that then the lines get truncated on screen.

My code also uses `Export-Csv` to create a table-style file without truncation you can simply open in Excel.

Comment: Again, sorry if the title is misleading, I tried to make this clear in the descrition of the issue, and in reply to the first few comments I got : these are two distinct parts of the same task. First I would need to create a list of short strings read at a given location of each file, this list being meant to run a “simultaneous search” with WinHex ; then, in a later step, once I know which “B” files have a match with “A” files, I would need to do checksum calculations. I will add an example. Thanks for this anyway, I may be able to adapt the relevant parts to get the intended result.

Comment: As I mentioned, the problem I got when running tests with [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes is that it's taking too long, seemingly parsing each file fully before extracting the requested small string near the beginning. With this method is it going to read only the requested bytes ? And I still don't understand why I got those errors when adding the [bitconverter]::ToString line.

Comment: Right from the bat I get this error, saying (translated) : “Get-ChildItem : Impossible to find a parameter corresponding to the name « File ».” Is my installed version of PowerShell too old, or is there a typo somewhere ?

Comment: Did some tests with the first part of the script, got many errors (“[System.Byte[]] does not contain a method  named « new »” / [System.IO.FileStream] does not contain a method named « new »” / “the « position » property can't be found for this object” / “you can't call a method on an expression with the value Null”). Perhaps I should ask, what is the minimum version of PowerShell required for all the commands in the script above to work ?

Comment: @GabrielB Yes, I don't know what version of PowerShell you are using, but at the top of my head, you need version 5 to use the `::new()` constructor syntax. I have edited my answer and aadded inline comment to show how to do that with older versions. Of course, if you can, try to update to at least PS 5.1

Comment: I added an update to the original question. I installed PowerShell 5.1 (before I had v. 2.0, default with Windows 7, even the proposed workaround didn't work), then tested the first part of your script : it works almost as intended but I get one byte per line, how can I get one complete hex string on each line ? Thanks.

Comment: @GabrielB Ah I see, you're right. I have redone the joining of hex values by first getting an array of values and in a second line `$hex = $hex -join ''` joining them together as a single string.

Comment: Alright, that way it works perfectly, thanks ! Would you care to add an explanation for each term of the `$hex = for...` line ? Also, how can I add the name of the file at the end of each line, preceded by a space or tabulation ? With `-Value $hex,$file.FullName` the name is added to the next line ; without the comma it's added right afterward with no space ; with a space in between it doesn't work. Oh, but it seems to work with quotation marks. // I may need some more help later on for the checksum script, but now at least I should be able to run the first part.

Comment: @GabrielB Added explanation